# Write sql for if column A or Column B is in specific value or both column A and B is in specific value then display it

Tags: mysql, sql

this is 'relationship' table

[image]

This is 'relationship_funder' table

[image]

To connect the two table, do the

```
select * from relationship 
join relationship_funder on relationship.id = relationship_funder.relationship_id
```

The problem I facing right now is to produce a sql for only

'one of the buyer_id or funder_id is 23 or both buyer_id and funder_id are 23'

should be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM relationship r
INNER JOIN relationship_funder rf
    ON r.id = rf.relationship_id
WHERE
    r.buyer_id = 23 OR rf.funder_id = 23;
```

Comment: and I also want if buyer_id and funder_id is 23 , then show it too

Comment: @bathulahmahir My logic will also cover this case.